# Inno Setup get TObject type/class in event handler

Tags: class, object, inno-setup, pascalscript, tobject

I have an event procedure that checks the `OnKeyUp` key press for two objects/controls (`TNewEdit` and `TNewComboBox`). Both objects need to be completed before a `TNewButton` gets enabled.

However, I cannot find a way to know how to get the type of the `Sender: TObject`, if that is `TNewEdit` or `TNewComboBox`.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you need to know the type for?

Comment: Show us some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to know the type/class for anything.

Such a need is a sign of a bad design.

---

If the handling of the event is different for each type/class, create a separate handler for each.

If part of the handling is common, call the common handler from the specific handlers.

```pascal
var
  Edit: TNewEdit;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;

procedure CommonKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);  
begin
  Log('Common handling');
end;

procedure EditKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Log('Edit key up');
  CommonKeyUp(Sender, Key, Shift);
end;

procedure ComboBoxKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Log('Combo box key up');
  CommonKeyUp(Sender, Key, Shift);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { ... }

  Edit.OnKeyUp := @EditKeyUp;
  Combobox.OnKeyUp := @ComboBoxKeyUp;
end;
```

---

Though as you actually have two controls, you probably want to distinguish, what control raised the event.

That's, what the `Sender` argument is for. The following code shows how to use it. But again, in general, this is not the right way to go.

```pascal
var
  Edit: TNewEdit;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;

procedure ControlKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Sender = Edit then
  begin
    Log('Edit key up');
  end
    else
  if Sender = ComboBox then
  begin
    Log('Combo box key up');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Other key up');
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { ... }

  Edit.OnKeyUp := @ControlKeyUp;
  Combobox.OnKeyUp := @ControlKeyUp;
end;
```

---

Though still I do not understand, what you need this for.

You have to check both controls every time, so why do you need to know, what control, was the one that changed?

Also, to detect a change, do not use `OnKeyUp`, use `OnChange`. That way you capture all changes (key press, drag&drop, copy&paste, anything).

```pascal
var
  Edit: TNewEdit;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;
  Button: TNewButton;

procedure ControlChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button.Enabled := (Edit.Text <> '') and (ComboBox.Text <> '');
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { ... }

  Edit.OnChange := @ControlChange;
  Combobox.OnChange := @ControlChange;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps!